# how do i increase the line width of the mt carver addon in blender

Tags: python

I draw a line using MT Carver, and a tutorial video by jayanaman says to "increase the width, do it like this" but that method doesn't show any hotkeys that are used. When I draw a line then draw downward for the thickness, it's still connected at the first point, so it only creates a triangle. I would like to increase the thickness like the Solidify modifier. I'm using blender 2.79b with Carver 1,1,7.

[image]

Comment: You can't increase the line width, share the tutorial video link